# Catching PrematureCloseException from WebClient returning a Flux

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webclient, reactor-netty

How can I catch `reactor.netty.http.client.PrematureCloseException` when using `org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient` to retrieve and infinite `reactor.core.publisher.Flux`?

To reproduce the problem I've created two trivial Spring Boot applications. 
Both are based on `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux`.

The server code is:

```java
@RestController
public class TestserverRestController {

    @GetMapping(value="/huge-flux", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE)
    public Flux<Long> hugeFlux() {
        return Flux.range(1, Integer.MAX_VALUE).interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1));
    }

    @Autowired
    ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext;

    @GetMapping(value="/stop")
    public void stop() {
        springContext.close();
    }
}
```

The client code is:

```java
@Component
public class TestclientRunner implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Flux<Long> flux = WebClient.create().get()
                .uri("http://localhost:9000/huge-flux")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(Long.class);
        flux.subscribe(val -> System.out.printf("Value %d%n", val));
    }
}
```

By hitting `http://localhost:9000/stop` in a web browser the client
is terminated, and this error appears on the console of the client.

```
WARN 15635 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive : [id: 0x82a94759, L:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:61812] An exception has been observed post termination, use DEBUG level to see the full stack: reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: reactor.netty.http.client.PrematureCloseException: Connection prematurely closed DURING response
```

I want to be able to catch that error so that I can recover.  (In my real
project there will be alternate servers to connect to if one fails.)

Things I have tried in the client include:

```java
flux.doOnCancel(()-> log.warning("CANCEL"));
flux.doOnTerminate(()-> log.warning("TERMINATE"));
flux.doOnComplete(()-> log.warning("COMPLETE"));
flux.doOnDiscard(Object.class, (o)-> log.warning("DISCARD"));
flux.doOnError((e)-> log.warning("ERROR"));
```

but none of these log messages get printed when the server terminates.

Comment: Where did you put the `flux.doOnError`? Before or after the `flux.subscribe`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By replacing the `flux.subsribe()` line in the client code with:

```
            flux.subscribe(
                    val -> System.out.printf("Value %d%n", val),
                    ex -> System.err.printf("ERROR CONSUMER [%s] %s", ex.getClass(), ex.getMessage()),
                    () -> System.err.printf("COMPLETE CONSUMER"));
```

the issue can be captured by the error consumer (printing "ERROR CONSUMER").

Answer (score 0):

##### For those who are experiencing a similar issue with Mono

In my case only `onErrorResume` is able to catch the `PrematureCloseException`. I put it after `bodyToMono(...)` method. None of `doOnError`, `onErrorMap`, `onErrorReturn` helped me.

```java
.onErrorResume(throwable -> {
                 // put your fallback actions here
                 // E.g. I just rethrow another exception
                 throw new YourException("Request failed due to " + throwable.getMessage());
               })
```

**Note:** I'm also using `block` method for subscription

**Versions:**

- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:3.0.4

  - org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty:3.0.4

    - io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-http:1.1.4
  - org.springframework:spring-webflux:6.0.6

    - io.projectreactor:reactor-core:3.5.3